# Running commands when switching to gui mode?

Tags: vimrc, gvim

I only recently realized that I have a `vimx` binary installed that allows me to switch from terminal mode to gui mode with the `:gui` command. This is nice but it has complicated my configuration somewhat, because there are some settings that I want to be different depending on whether I am running in terminal mode or not.

Is there a way to run a set of commands when switching from terminal
mode to gui mode (and back again, if that's possible)?

Comment: It might be good to explain what settings you have set for terminal mode and gui mode?

Comment: Check this out

`au GUIEnter * echomsg "Hi, this is GUI!"`


:he GUIEnter

Comment: @AlexKroll that's exactly what I was looking for. If you're feeling motivated you should post that as an answer.